# Terminal, how to quit --More-- list

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

I use autocomplete a lot in the terminal, like for example for `cp` command. But sometimes, when I am putting in the directory for the `cp` command and I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the list of files is so long that Ubuntu spits out part of the list and then waits for key input before sequentially listing the rest of the files, one by one. This feature is near useless because you never know how many files are left, and almost always end up with an error.

Is there some way to leave this list and go back to my `cp` command, or do I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and start typing in my `cp` command again?

Comment: @David Bash's tab completion doesn't use a pager. The readline library does this. It just uses the most common pager's keybindings.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can type in the <kbd>Q</kbd> key. ...

Comment: ...from `quit` ;)

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't directly answer your question (@saiarco895 did that), but I hate the default behavior of tab-completion in bash for the same reason. Assuming you're using Bash, you can change the behavior of the readline library it uses by editing the `~/.inputrc` file. I put the following in it:

```
set menu-complete-display-prefix On
"\CTAB": possible-completions
TAB: menu-complete
"\x1b[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

which allows me to cycle through completion options without printing them out using `tab` and `shift-tab`. If I need to see a print-out of all options, I use `alt-shift-?`